# Performance decreases with EF LINQ joins

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

Any clues to this issue is most welcome.

I use EF4 and need to loop a huge amount of records, so performance is a priority.

Therefore i have placed my lookuptables in static memory (List(table entity)) for faster access.

But I havde noticed that if I have used a joined Linq expression to fill my static List , calling the static data perform slower than if I just entered the whole table unfiltered in my List.

Consider following example:

```
private static List<MMoptions> _testJOINED;
private static List<MMoptions> _testALONE;

protected  void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
  _testJOINED = new List<MMoptions>(); 
  _testALONE = new List<MMoptions>();

    using (var context = new LBEntities())
    {                

    _testJOINED = (from opt in context.MMoptions
                     join ctr in context.MMcontrols on opt.opControlID equals ctr.ctrID
                     join mod in context.MMmodel on ctr.ctrModelID equals mod.mID
                     where mod.mActive == true
                     select opt).ToList();

    _testALONE = context.MMoptions.ToList();
}

Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();

st.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
    var opt = _testALONE.Where(f => f.opParent == "RANGE_BU" && f.opSelectValue == "RANGE4").FirstOrDefault();
  }

st.Stop();   
Response.Write("testALONE:" + st.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

st.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
   {
     var opt = _testJOINED.Where(f => f.opParent == "RANGE_BU" && f.opSelectValue == "RANGE4").FirstOrDefault();
   }

 st.Stop();
 Response.Write("testJOINED:" + st.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());


}
```

testJoined(10000records) perform at 1400ms

testAlone(17000records) performs at 6ms

I dont get it, are the joined data inherited into my List as dead weight, at som point?

Regards

Mark

UPDATE.

I notice if i omit the second join (to MMmodel) the performance are equal.
EF model shows correct relations between the 3 tables.

Comment: If you change ordering do you get same results? I.e. first loop through joined and then alone

Comment: @Giorgi yes same results when I switch the order.

Comment: Then the only guess is that alone has much less count of rows then joined. Searching in big list no metter that you have same count of iterations will be of course slower. Try selecting distinct options in joined and i am sure times will be the same. Looping 10000 times through 20000 rows and 10000 times through billion of rows will differ of course.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is caused by the fact that the `_testJOINED` is being populated only when you call the `_testJOINED.Where` function. This is called **Deferred Execution**, and you can find more details on this on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx), under the same title. 
You should measure the population of both collections separately, and you would see that the `_testJOINED` is populated in no time, while the `_testALONE` is taking some time.

Comment: I don't think that is correct. A ToList would make it execute immediately, not wait for the Where.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose That's why OP should measure the time it takes to populate as well. Only then it will be clear. Otherwise even if the collections are of the same size, the time it takes to find all matches and return the first would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it is appreciated. I used the Tolist with the intention to bypass Deferred Execution. When I run the to examples seperately I get the same results. 
What puzzles me is that the filling method invokes on performance of the static List.

Comment: @neghV4r I dont mind a long population timing (its a one time event) , Its the following performance of the static List which is the big showstopper for me.

Comment: Sadly, ended up using Datatable as static lookup. 
Performed better.